# PHP Cron Job issue with Namespace

Tags: php, cron, namespaces

I'm having some trouble with a cron job and namespace, I'm trying to implement this function which works great!

https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8

http://www.irook.com/test/test.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('/home/irookcom/public_html/test/encoding.php'); 
use \ForceUTF8\Encoding;  // It's namespaced now.

echo Encoding::fixUTF8("FÃÂ©dération Camerounaise de Football\n");

?>
```

This works fine when called from a browser, but when I add a cron job:

/ramdisk/bin/php5 /home4/irookcom/public_html/test/test.php

I get these errors:

```
[14-Nov-2015 09:17:01] PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  '\'     (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home4/irookcom/public_html/test/test.php on line 7
[14-Nov-2015 09:17:01] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING,     expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in     /home4/irookcom/public_html/test/test.php on line 7
```

Is there a work around for the use function that the cron job would accept?

Comment: Please format the error message with code tags.

Comment: Verify which php binary is used when using a cronjob - and try the "use"-line at the beginning of the script right after "<?php".

Comment: Error message code tags added.  Using PHP Version 5.4.43.  I tried moving the use to right after the "<?php" but same error.

Comment: Which PHP version do you use when running from the web server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the PHP version was it.  The server was running 5.4 for web calls but 5.2 for the cron calls - changed it to force 5.4, and it works like a charm!